# Which connection string should I use with an application role in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

My client set up an application Role in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 for one database. He doesn't know how to change the connection string for that role and I have any idea about which connection string to use for this purpose.

Can anyone provide me an example of a connection string for an application role defined in MSSQL?

Comment: You would not change the connection string, the user would login then then sp_setapprole needs to be executed in the client to switch to the app roles security context

Comment: Ok.. But at the moment I have a connection string with AttachFile .. and the MDF is attached to the application. How to change the connectionstring properly to not use AttachedFiles ?

Answer (score 0):

To not use AttachedFile in the connection you need to attach the mdf file to a SQL Server. Once attached you could use a connection similar to the one below but many examples can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase; User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```